# Did i correctly implement the recursive add function? My front node is remaining null

Tags: java

I am supposed to implement a recursive linked list, but after writing the code and debugging, it seems that my front node is remaining unchanged (it is staying at null). Any help will be appreciated.

```java
public class RecursiveLinkedCollection<T> implements CollectionInterface<T> {
    
    LLNode<T> front;
    int size = 0;
    
    RecursiveLinkedCollection() {
        front = null;
        size = 0;
        
    }

    private LLNode<T> recAdd(LLNode<T> node, T data) {
        
        if(node == null) {
            LLNode<T> newNode = new LLNode<T>(data);
            node = newNode;
        }
        if(node.getLink() == null) {
            LLNode<T> newNode = new LLNode<T>(data);
            node.setLink(newNode);
            return newNode;
        }
        return recAdd(node.getLink(), data);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(T data) {
        recAdd(front, data);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well you never set `front` if it's null.

Comment: But doesn't the line 'if(node == null) { LLNode<T> newNode = new LLNode<T>(data); node = newNode; } ' set front to the newNode if the list is empty (front = null)?

Comment: That only sets the local variable `node` to null.

Comment: [Java is always pass-by-value.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40523/7082956)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your `add` method, you try to append the new node from the `front`-node. In your recursion if you check for `node` being null, this can only happen if `front` is not set. You try to set `node = newNode`, but because [java is always pass-by-value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40523/7082956) the reference to `front` is never set.

```java
public class RecursiveLinkedCollection<T> implements CollectionInterface<T> {
    
    LLNode<T> head;
    int size;
    
    RecursiveLinkedCollection() {
    }

    private LLNode<T> recToTail(LLNode<T> next, T data) {
        LLNode<T> newNode = new LLNode<T>(data);
        if(next == null) {
            head = newNode;
            size++;
            return head;
        }
        if(next.getLink() == null) {
            next.setLink(newNode);
            size++;
            return newNode;
        }
        return recAdd(next.getLink(), data);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(T data) {
        return recAdd(head, data) != null;
    }
}
```

Comment: ahh i think I understand now! so basing off this, is this how the recursive remove method should be? 'private LLNode<T> recRemove(LLNode<T> node, T data) {
  if(node == null) {
   return null;
  }
  if(node.equals(data)) {
   LLNode<T> newNode = new LLNode<T>(data);
   head = newNode;
   newNode.setLink(node.getLink());
   size--;
   return newNode;
  }
  return recRemove(node.getLink(), data);
 }
 

 @Override
 public boolean remove(T data) {
  return recRemove(head, data) != null;
  
 }'

Comment: I see multiple problems with your recRemove method. First one, `if (node.equals(data))` will never be true, because node and data are instances from different classes. And the second if you try to delete data from your list, you remove the old node, create a new node and place and chain the next nodes to it, yet you lose the connection to the previous node.